# How to use the value of Get() method of user to display appropirate Image?

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I am trying to use the year value obtained by the user to display the appropriate image.
for example, if the user inputted the year 2021 to view a certain image of that year , I would want the correct image displayed. I'm having trouble with my if statements, if I'm using it correctly that is. I am still new to coding and python so any help and advice would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image

main = Tk()
main.geometry("750x250")
main.title("Publication Year Search")

L1 = Label(main, text="Publication Year", fg='black')
L1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=10)

def getDate():
    date = EB.get()
    image = Image.open('pic-1.png')
    if date == 2021:
        image.open()

EB = Entry(main, width=10)
EB.grid(row=0,column=2)

buttonSub = Button(main, text= 'Search', command=getDate)
buttonSub.grid(row=3,column=2)

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: `date` is a string, so `date == 2021` will be always false.  Either changing `date` to integer by `date = int(EB.get())` (note that you need to cater invalid number input) or use `date == '2021'`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you, Ive used date == '2021' and I'm getting this error:  Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/khadraabdirahman/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Test/testgui.py", line 17, in getDate
    image.open()
  File "/Users/khadraabdirahman/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 519, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: open

Comment: The error obviously tells you that `image` has no attribute `open`, so what do you want to do on the line `image.open()` actually?

Comment: @acw1668 I am trying to open a certain image depending on the value inputted by the user. So if the user inputs the year 2021 for the publication year, the corrosponding image would be displayed. Same case if they inputted the year 2022, a different yet corresponding image would be displayed.

Comment: Then you need to use `Image.open("...")` to open the image you want, like you did before the if line.

Comment: @acw1668 ive used just that but I get this other error: File "/Users/khadraabdirahman/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Test/testgui.py", line 18
    Image.open("Test/pic-1.png")
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Read the error please, it is obviously the problem line has indentation issue.